# ReferenceError: is not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with several Google charts that works fine but I want to load the functions only when I load this specific page, to optimize loading time on other pages.
Unfortunately I keep getting:

```
ReferenceError: drawRevenuesExpenses is not defined
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRevenuesExpenses);
```

My page looks like this:

Footer.php (common to all my pages) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!-- For general javascript functions -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

home.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Some JS functions
   if(document.getElementById('include_charts')){ // Problem is here

      //GOOGLE CHARTS START
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRevenuesExpenses);
      function drawRevenuesExpenses() {
         // my chart
      }
}
```

The problem is introduced ONLY if I add `if(document.getElementById('include_charts'))`
I tried using `if (window.location.href == 'http://127.0.0.1/project/Controller')` but I have the same error.

It seems checking if a div ID exists or the current URL doesn't work. I added an "alert" in the loop and it's executed correctly.

Comment: The error means that the variable doesn't exist at the moment you want to use it. Create the function before you use it. Or better yet: inline the definition or use a function expression. Function declarations inside blocks behave weirdly (because they are actually invalid).

Comment: so stupid of me! that worked thanks!